# Fast paste 10K rows table from Excel to Word (horizontal pages)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, paste

There was some questions about pasting, but can't find solution for my problem.
I have to paste table from Excel to Word but when I paste table with about 10 thousand rows and 20 columns it takes a lot of time for showing results in about 700 horizontal pages. I know it is a lot but is there any fast way for pasting really long tables from Excel to Word?

Comment: Have you timed copying the table to Word without using code?

Comment: A major speed factor is the fact the Word will *layout* each and every page generated - that takes a *long* time with tables. You can *try* first switching to Word's **Draft View**, see if that makes any difference. Also turn Word's Application.ScreenUpdating to false. But it will still be a slow process.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt yes, took about about 10 minutes without any code.

Comment: @CindyMeister ScreenUpdating not helps. But I have not tried Draft View, thank you, I will check it as soon as possible.

Comment: So now that you know the process takes 10 mins without code it gives you something to compare to. Using code isn’t likely to be much faster. Personally I would be questioning whether it is absolutely necessary to copy that much data across to Word and be thinking of alternative solutions.

Comment: Word's performance with tables is always slow. There are things that can speed up table processing once it's in the document but trying to paste a table containing 200,000 cells is asking a bit much. Why are you trying to do this in Word, anyway?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is necessary in my job..

Comment: @CindyMeister Draft View not helps but thank you for response!

Comment: The only other possibility would be to feed the content in as delimited text then use Convert Text To Table. The question is, though, whether converting the Excel content to text loses information that can only be brought across through copy/paste. Other than that, you'd have to leave the realm of VBA and look at leveraging the Office Open XML file format to transfer the content. It could be a *huge* project, though, depending on what kind of Excel content is involved.

Comment: Maybe you should ask what makes this 'necessary'. It certainly isn't necessary if all you want to produce is a document with some nicely-formatted text before/after a 700-page table.